# How can I get changes from master into feature branch

Tags: windows, git

Using windows 7 and git version 2.5.3 and I am trying to update my featurebranch with the latest from the master:

```
git checkout myfeaturebranch
git pull origin master
```

There are no errors but when I go:

```
git checkout master
```

then one of the files is different to the same file in the featurebranch. What could have caused this? Did I stuff up the tracking settings or what could it be? I would expect it to be the same?

Comment: Did you change this file in your feature branch?

Comment: Also, did you do a `git pull` (with optional `origin master`) with the *local* `master` checked out? Your local `master` branch is *not* automatically updated when you perform a `pull` on a different branch.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is just simply pull the remote tracking from master. Then when you checkout master again, there is no different.
If you meant to merge current master to your feature branch. You can do this:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout featurebranch
git merge master
```

Comment: While on a feature branch, `git pull origin master` *will* merge the current master to that branch.

Comment: that is what I thought

Comment: I just tried it on the master and getting: There is no tracking information for the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add tracking: git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master